# How to stop rats from walking in plastic sewage pipe and damaging it?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, pipe, sewer

A rat has scratched open a big hole in a plastic sewage pipe near the toilet. After closing the hole with a metal plate and taping it with power tape, the rat has started scratching again. How to stop it from destroying the pipe again?

Comment: Where on this planet are you, and why do you have rats in your sewer system to begin with?

Comment: Are you on a city sewer system, or on a septic system?

Comment: Why is it strange that rats are in the sewer system?

Comment: on a Septic system

Comment: You'd think there'd be rodentproofing measures in place to keep rats from getting in to begin with...perhaps making it so there aren't rats in the system would be a start? (Rodents can't exactly go about not gnawing on things -- if you were a rodent, you'd understand ;)

Comment: but plastic? who likes chewing plastic or did they get used to it eating modern food?

Comment: they gnaw on it to sharpen their teeth and keep them from growing out of control (which'd be quite the disaster if you were a rodent!)

Answer (score 1):

Step one: eliminate the rats.

Step two: find their means of ingress and block it off.

Pictures of the pipe where it exits the house, the cover on the access port of the tank, and the area of the ground that's above the tank would help suggestions flow in to accomplish these steps. Failing that, those are the places that you'd need to inspect, to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

We are also experiencing rats gnawing the toilet paste outlet pipe from the inside.  We've had to have the pipe replaced twice in the last 6 months.
This is on the first floor, so they are climbing up one-story of the waste pipe from the inside!
I understand that rats thrive in sewers, have even seen the word 'epidemic'.

My plumber has recommended that I:

1. remove the attraction. They like the clear drinking water in the toilet bowl, so we add bleach to it every night,
2. dissuade them. We flush more bleach at night, which is a bad smell for them.  I'm told peppermint oil and caster oil are good
3. stop them getting into the pipe in the first place. Fit a one-way block to the waste pipe, between your house and the sewers

PS. Keep the toilet seat down.  Otherwise they can climb round the u-bend and into your house! Yuck!!