# My neighbor has rodent issues which is causing me issues. What can be done from a code enforcement standpoint?

Tags: crawlspace, pest, rodent

My neighbor has rodent issues which is causing me issues. What can be done from a code enforcement standpoint?

We have now have rodents trying to get into our crawl space. Our pest control servicer has told us they’re originating from next door. I got the property manager’s info, and am waiting to hear but.

Worst case scenario is that they are unhelpful. What steps should I take after that?

Comment: Will depend on your local code enforcement/regulations.  This will range from nothing at all to your neighbour signing over their first born or similar.

Comment: This certainly hinges on your municipality, so you'll have to cite your city to get any useful help. If you're in a mere county, I'm pretty confident that you've got no recourse.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question dependent upon location, not necessarily a DIY question. The question should be edited to make it applicable to this stack or moved to an appropriate stack.

Comment: [How to stop rats from walking in plastic sewage pipe and damaging it?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103257/how-to-stop-rats-from-walking-in-plastic-sewage-pipe-and-damaging-it) "Step one: eliminate the rats. Step two: **find their means of ingress and block it off**. "

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue of "code", as that usually refers to enforcement of the building codes. This has to do with city or town ordinances, the local health department/board, and/or other town/city offices.

Having said that, mice are really easy to catch with just cheap traps, and poison stations. Unless your neighbor has an absolute dump with food all over the place, just keep placing traps at a rate faster than they breed. And place a formal complaint with the authorities.